# Game in Swift 2 - "touchesBegan"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, game-physics

I want to build a game that when I touch and drag, in the place of the touch it creates a line that goes in the same direction as the drag, and ends in the boundaries of the game (in this case my frame).

Any tips of how could I approach this problem?

Comment: pls show what you tried

Comment: Pls try searching. It's not like no one's ever done this before.

Comment: BTW, I see that you have your full email address in your SO profile. I would suggest changing that. Say something like Julian at <domain> at the least. Otherwise web crawlers will find your email, sell it to spam mailing lists, and you will **drown** in spam.

Answer (score 0):

Your search term in UIPanGestureRecognizer.

You'd create a pan gesture recognizer and attach it to your view. In the method that it calls, look for the state UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan. Record the start position, then respond to calls to your action method with the state UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged.

That should be enough to get you started. As Matt says, this is a fairly common use case, so you should be able to find sample code online if you can't work this out from the docs.